# phpMyAdmin, an 'if'-esque type statement for 2 foreign key fields in 1 table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, phpmyadmin

As the title suggests, I will have difficulty explaining this. :p

I have three tables in phpMyAdmin setup.

Within one of the tables, contains two foreign keys. For e.g foo_ID and bar_ID. These have been indexed and are displaying fields names.

Is it possible to constrain what can be selected in bar_ID after first selecting something from foo_ID?

If x=1
  print = 6-10
else
 print 1-10

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it with a constraint, but if you really wanted to you could achieve it with a trigger.

However i personally would but that kind of validation logic in the app layer, unless people are going to be using the database directly.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just do something along the lines of

```
SELECT IF(x = 1,'6-10',1-10') AS range
FROM table
```